# Getting ctags + Vim to work with scoping?

Tags: vim, ctags

When I use ctags to generates tags of the STL and use those tags with Vim, it isn't aware of scoping.  If I use ctrl-] it will go to the first tag that matches, even if that is incorrect.  For example:

```
std::list<int> mylist;
mylist.push__back(100);
```

if I type ctrl-] while the cursor is over push_back(100), it will take me to the bitvector's implementation of push_back instead of list's.

As far as I know ctags isn't aware of scope but I know there are some Vim plugins that use ctags that are, such as OmniCppComplete.  Is anyone aware of any plugins or settings that will fix this?

Answer (score 4):

What options are you passing to ctags?  `--extra=+q`  may help...

Comment: -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=c++

So I'm already doing that...

Comment: hmm.. Thanks for the upvote anyway.  I'm a ctags/omnicppcomplete noob, I just happened to have just installed and run that :)

Comment: @JohnWeldon is --extra=+q  always needed? what is its side effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally do "gctrl-]" (notice the 'g'). This will open you a list of relative tag position. You'll have to choose one and vim will bring you to the file position.

[Vimp jumps](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_to_definition_using_g)
Give you better perspectives of available jumps. You can jump to local or global or whatever declaration.

And effectively, some plugins change the function in charge to bring you to the definition and so, give you better GoToDeclaration system.